# Remove Null values from SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, null

I have an SQL query

```
SELECT 
    EXPORT_MONTH "EXPORT_MONTH",          
    EXPORT_PROD "EXPORT_PROD",                      
    QUANTITY "QUANTITY"         
 FROM EXPORT_IMPORT
  LEFT OUTER JOIN  EXPORT_DATE
ON EXPORT_MONTH (EXPORT MONTH) <= 
EXPORT_PROD_CYCLE_YEAR_MONTH
ORDER BY EXPORT_MONTH DESC;
```

which produces the following output

**Current Output**

```
EXPORT_MONTH","EXPORT_PROD","QUANTITY

'198609',null,null
'198608',null,null
'198607',null,null
'198606','2287472','4961023'
'198605','1820387','4591548'
'198604','2305491','7171038'
'198603','2247472','4961023'
'198602','1810387','4591548'
'198601','2315491','7171038'
```

I'm trying yield the following output

**Expected Output**

```
EXPORT_MONTH","EXPORT_PROD","QUANTITY

'198606','2287472','4961023'
'198605','1820387','4591548'
'198604','2305491','7171038'
'198603','2247472','4961023'
'198602','1810387','4591548'
'198601','2315491','7171038'
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c90b4568fe89532574884446f3585854

Comment: use `inner join` instead of `left outer join`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT EXPORT_MONTH, EXPORT_PROD, QUANTITY         
FROM EXPORT_IMPORT i INNER JOIN
     EXPORT_DATE d
     ON EXPORT_MONTH <= EXPORT_PROD_CYCLE_YEAR_MONTH
ORDER BY EXPORT_MONTH DESC;
```